# Iterate JSON to create innerHTML links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Alright I've been scouring Stack Overflow for a while now but can't seem to find the solution to my problem.  I'm trying to iterate through the JSON to pull all the `ids` and `dates` in each `top_worst` section.  The JSON looks like this:

```
[
{
    "timerName": "FT:Tree",
    "top_worst": [
        {
            "id": 44083,
            "date": "2015-07-14T21:31:58+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 44059,
            "date": "2015-07-14T20:00:58+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 44119,
            "date": "2015-07-14T23:30:31+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 44065,
            "date": "2015-07-14T20:20:46+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 43981,
            "date": "2015-07-14T15:20:50+00:00"
        }
    ],
    "daily_percentile_90th": 26651,
    "daily_average": 22076
},
{
    "timerName": "Search:Blog",
    "top_worst": [
        {
            "id": 44087,
            "date": "2015-07-14T21:28:48+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 44087,
            "date": "2015-07-14T21:22:54+00:00"
        }
    ],
    "daily_percentile_90th": 9248.1,
    "daily_average": 9040.5
},
{
    "timerName": "Search:ViewImage",
    "top_worst": [
        {
            "id": 44152,
            "date": "2015-07-15T01:04:53+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 44092,
            "date": "2015-07-14T21:41:27+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 44230,
            "date": "2015-07-15T05:22:44+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 44074,
            "date": "2015-07-14T20:40:57+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 44098,
            "date": "2015-07-14T22:03:25+00:00"
        }
    ],
    "daily_percentile_90th": 6545.6,
    "daily_average": 5571.49
}
]
```

So the problem is that my for-loop causes issues because not all of the timers have a top_worst section, so it throws an error when I try to use `.length` in the for-loop.  The goal is to get a link inside the table cell using the id as part of the link, and then using the date as the visible part.  See image below if you are confused (don't worry, I am too, clearly).  Here is my HTML code so you can see what's going on:

```
function createTable(jsonData){
$.each(jsonData, function(i, item){

    var daily90th = (item.daily_percentile_90th/1000).toFixed(2);
    var dailyAverage = (item.daily_average/1000).toFixed(2);

    var $tr = $("<tr class='clickable'>").append(
        $("<td align='left'>").text(item.timerName),
        $("<td class='daily90'>").text(daily90th),
        $("<td class='dailyAvg'>").text(dailyAverage)).appendTo("#reportTable");

    var $ta = $("<tr id='spaces"+(i)+"'>").append(
        $("<td id='createLinks"+(i)+"'>")).appendTo("#reportTable");


        var where = document.getElementById('createLinks'+(i));
        where.innerHTML = "<a href='http:/example.com/example.html?id=44217'>2015-07-15T04:43:49+00:00</a>";            

});
}
```

Any help on this at all would be great!!!  Here's a fiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/rg2s7Lqk/1/

This is what it looks like on my site, but instead of one static link, I need to dynamically create them.

[image: This is what it looks like on my site, but instead of one static link, I need to dynamically create them.]

THANKS YOU GUYS!!!!

Comment: Could you post the code that is not working for you?

Comment: I just put the last couple lines in a for-loop like this: 
`for(var k=0; k > jsonData.top_worst.length; k++){
 var where = document.getElementById('createLinks'+i);
 where.innerHTML = "<a href='http://example.com/example.html?id='+jsonData[i].top_worst[k].id'>Waterfall</a>";
}`
@Joe but the for-loop leaves this error: Cannot read property of length undefined.  It does that if I use any of the following in place:
1) jsonData[i].top_worst.id
2) jsonData.top_worst[i].id  ETC.  It's because some of the JSON values don't come with the top_worst.  Is there a way to skip over those?

Comment: You are replacing the inner HTML on each iteration. Try appending to the element instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Joe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with a normal `for` loop?

```
var where = $('#createLinks'+(i));
for (var i in item.top_worst) {
    var bad = item.top_worst[i];
    console.log(bad);
    where.append("<a href='http://example.com/example.html?id=44217'>"+bad.date+"</a><br/>");
}
```

[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/rg2s7Lqk/3/)

Comment: The problem was I was being dumb and didn't use `var i in item.top_worst` instead of trying to use `top_worst.length`.  Thank you so much @StoyanDekov !!!